# Python GAE Problems with combining requestHandler and BlobstoreUploadHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob, handlers

```
<form action="/fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <label>Title<input name="name"></label>
  <label>Author<input name="author"></label>
  <label>Year <input name="year"></label>
  <label>Link <input name="link"></label>
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The question is why `self.get_uploads()` returns nothing,when `self.request.get('file')` works (or I suggest it works)

```
class FileUploadHandler(H.Handler,blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    name=self.request.get('name')
    if name:
        logging.error(name)
    author=self.request.get('author')
    if author:
        logging.error(author)
    year  =self.request.get('year')
    if year and year.isdigit():
        year=int(year)
    f  =self.get_uploads('file')#FILE NOT FOUND
    #f=self.request.get('file') # WORKS FINE

    if not f:
        logging.error("FILE NOT FOUND")
    self.redirect("/files")
```

I looked at the [sample app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) but they also use `self.request.get('file')`

The answer is that you should create upload url for blob.

Comment: So what is `get_uploads` supposed to be?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/ look here,it loads the file(files) from the POST request

Comment: Yes,u 're right,thanks. I found the answer earlier but I guess I didn't have reputation to answer for my question.By the way, upload_url must be declared something like that:
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/fileupload',max_bytes_per_blob=10*1000*1000)

Comment: Ok,sorry) btw,I have a working code for this problem,should I past it in the comments,or update a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `get_uploads()[0]` or name.

Simple example on the uploads handler (Compare and make appropriate changes in your code):

```
  <form name="myform" action="{{ upload_url }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>Select an Image</h1>
            <input name="file" type="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
```

Handler:

```
class UploadBlobsHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):

    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            logging.info(upload)
            url = images.get_serving_url(upload)
            # Do something with it.
        except:
            self.redirect('/uploadform/?error', abort=True)

        self.redirect('/uploadform/?success&image_url=' + url)
```

Example on how to use uploads with blobstorrhandlers: [gae-image-upload-example](https://github.com/jimmykane/gae-image-upload-example/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a full solution to my problem:

```
 <form action="{{upload_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label>Title<input name="name"></label>
    <label>Author<input name="author"></label>
    <label>Year <input name="year"></label>
    <label>Link <input name="link"></label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

where `upload_url =blobstore.create_upload_url('/fileupload',max_bytes_per_blob=10*1000*1000)`
and the code to process the request is next:

```
upload=self.get_uploads('file')[0]
```